# Rename multidimensional array keys

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I'm trying to rename my keys in a multidimensional array. I looked at this: [Renaming the keys in multidimensional associate arrays](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19167893/renaming-the-keys-in-multidimensional-associate-arrays) and it does rename it, but only for 1 of my 2 arrays. How can I get it to rename the 1st array `time` and the second array `count`?

My output right now is :

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => 00:00
            [1] => 00:15
            [2] => 00:30
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => 8
            [1] => 9
            [2] => 8
        )
)
```

I need `[0]` to be `time` and `[1]` to be `count`.

If I use this:

```
foreach ($sliced_array as $id => $dataset) {
    $newArray["time"] = $dataset;
}
```

I can get it to output only array `[1]` renamed as `time`. It should be `count` and array `[0]` disappears entirely. Is there a way to focus which dataset the foreach targets? `dataset[0]` does not work.

My expected output is:

```
Array
(
    [time] => Array
        (
            [0] => 00:00
            [1] => 00:15
            [2] => 00:30
        )

    [count] => Array
        (
            [0] => 8
            [1] => 9
            [2] => 8
        )
)
```

Comment: Your expected output result looks like?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Did you just try:

```
$myArray["time"] = $myArray[0];
$myArray["count"] = $myArray[1];
unset($myArray[0]);
unset($myArray[1]);
```

or just:

```
$newArray["time"] = $myArray[0];
$newArray["count"] = $myArray[1];
```

?

Answer (score 2):

```
$newArray = array_combine(array('time','count'),$sliced_array);
```

https://www.php.net/array_combine